# Applying 'filter' on an array returns an empty result

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an array called 'myBelongings'. I need to filter the array based on a specific condition, which is item(s) with label 'Notebook'. Here is my code:

```
myBelongings = [
0: {value: 0, label: "Pen"}
1: {value: 1, label: "Handbag"}
2: {value: 2, label: "Notebook"}
2: {value: 3, label: "Laptop"}
];

let result  = myBelongings .filter((item)=>{ item.value== 'Notebook'});
```

However the result turns out to be an empty array. Could you help me find the fix?

Comment: It's not a valid array as you put it

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `myBelongings` is not a valid array. Assuming the array structure is corrected to -

```
const myBelongings = [
{value: 0, label: "Pen"},
{value: 1, label: "Handbag"},
{value: 2, label: "Notebook"},
{value: 3, label: "Laptop"}
];
```

Either omit the {}, or add `return` to the function call if you want to keep the curlies

```
let result  = myBelongings .filter((item)=> item.label == 'Notebook');
```

OR

```
let result  = myBelongings .filter((item)=>{ return item.label == 'Notebook'});
```

Check [this JSBin here](https://jsbin.com/degunefafe/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace `.value` with `.label`, also we need to remove the curly braces.

```
let result  = myBelongings .filter((item)=> item.value == 'Notebook');
```

or

```
let result  = myBelongings .filter((item)=> { return item.value == 'Notebook' });
```

Comment: Thanks.
I need to keep the curly braces, as the TSLint mandates.

Comment: Then we can just add a `return`.